# How to make an alias for grep which include ' character

Tags: bash, grep, alias

I would like to make an alias for this command:

```
 grep 'world  ' FILE
```

where I want it to display all the lines containing 'world  ' . The problem is that I cannot define it because the ' character is already used for defining the alias. Thus I cannot create an alias of command with something like this:

```
 alias name=' grep 'world  ' FILE
```

Comment: The _easy_ answer is `alias name=$' grep \'world  \' FILE`, but the _better_ answer is not to use an alias at all. Aliases don't let you do flow control; they make quoting more complicated; they can't be used in scripts without explicitly turning on off-by-default feature flags; they aren't guaranteed to be supported in POSIX-baseline shells; they don't show up in stack traces; they're otherwise worse than functions in every way.

Answer (score 2):

As in all things alias-related: Use a function instead.

```
name() { grep 'world  ' FILE "$@"; }
```